# Equivalence of INDEXPROPERTY in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server we have `INDEXPROPERTY` function. Example of usage: `INDEXPROPERTY(ObjectId, IndexName, 'IndexDepth')` Is there any PostgreSQL analogs? I didn't find any surfing the Internet.

**UPDATE:**
So we are currently migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL and I have to convert a dozen procedures. One of them is responsible of index rebuilding. In the original procedure we check do we have indexes for rebuild. Here is a piece of code I'm talking about:

```
SELECT @numberoftables = COUNT(DISTINCT objectname)
FROM #fraglist
WHERE (LogicalFrag >= @maxfrag OR [ScanDensity] < @mindensity)
     AND CountPages > 100
     AND INDEXPROPERTY(ObjectId, IndexName, 'IndexDepth') > 0;
```

`#fraglist` contains all indexes and their parameters.

Comment: I use T-SQL for 20+ years and I had to look up the documentation. What are you trying to achieve? Why use a function specifically instead of querying the system views?

Comment: What does this indexproperty do? What problem does it solve? All "properties" of an index can be seen in `pg_index`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I have just updated my question.

Comment: You would need to check for [index bloat](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance#Index_Bloat) to determine if you need an index rebuild. Or the queries [from here](https://github.com/ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation)

Comment: Do you have a (production) problem with indexes in PostgreSQL? I can't remember the last time I had to rebuild an index... And that has nothing to do with my age! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To determine the depth of a B-tree index, you need the `pageinspect` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pageinspect;

SELECT level FROM bt_metap('indexname');
```

Note that this counts the number of *intermediate* levels, so an index that consists only of the root page will have a depth of 0.

This function requires superuser privileges.

Comment: Is that a valid thing to check in order to determine if an index needs a rebuild?

Comment: Not at all. But it is what was asked for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually we rebuild indexes after updating huge amount of rows. It should make our indexes faster.

Comment: @JosephKatzman: well, Postgres is not SQL Server. You need to apply different rules to identify indexes needing rebuild (in my experience, you need this far less in Postgres compared to SQL Server). The bloat check I mentioned in my comments is the better way to schedule this.

Comment: @JosephKatzman: While standardization is a good thing it unfortunately can lead to the misconception that databases are interchangeable components. **They are not**.  A good and appropriate read would be: [Migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).